# Passing a CComSafeArray across a COM boundary

Tags: c++, memory, com, atl

I'm trying to (i) get a safearray of longs across a COM boundary and (ii) use CComSafeArray for convenience.

My problem is that I'm getting unpredictable crashes after setting the COM property (see **pPrologue->EligibleProducts = var;** below). I've found it very hard to understand how to use CComSafeArray from the Microsoft documentation, can anyone shed any light? Thank you in advance!

In the IDL I have:

```
[propget, id(1), helpstring("property EligibleProducts")] HRESULT EligibleProducts([out, retval] VARIANT* pVal);
[propput, id(1), helpstring("property EligibleProducts")] HRESULT EligibleProducts([in] VARIANT newVal);
```

My server code is:

```
STDMETHODIMP CPrologue::put_EligibleProducts(VARIANT newVal)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())

    //start by clearing out any existing data
    m_EligibleProducts.clear();

    if(newVal.vt | (VT_ARRAY & VT_I4))
    {
        //construct a wrapper class with the passed in SAFEARRAY
         CComSafeArray<long> wrapper;
         wrapper.Attach(newVal.parray);

         int iProductID = 0;

         //loop through products and add them to our vector
         int iCount = wrapper.GetCount();
         for(int iIndex = 0; iIndex < iCount; iIndex++)
         {
             iProductID = wrapper.GetAt(iIndex);
             if(iProductID > 0)
             {
                 m_EligibleProducts.push_back(iProductID);
             }
         }

         hr = S_OK;

    return hr;
}
```

And my calling code is:

```
                VARIANT var;
                ::VariantInit(&var);
                var.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_I4;

                CComSafeArray<long> wrapper;

                for(std::vector<long>::const_iterator it = products.begin(); it != products.end(); it++)
                {
                    wrapper.Add(*it);
                }

                //get the SAFEARRAY from the wrapper
                var.parray = wrapper.Detach();

                //and store it on the appropriate business object
                IProloguePtr pPrologue = pCustomer->Prologue;    
                **pPrologue->EligibleProducts = var;**

                //clean up the variant (and hence SAFEARRAY)
                ::VariantClear(&var);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if(newVal.vt | (VT_ARRAY & VT_I4))

This doesn't do what you seem to think it does. This condition is always true. You are looking for `if (newVal.vt == VT_ARRAY | VT_I4)`

In `put_EligibleProducts`, you have `Attach`ed CComSafeArray to the pointer inside VARIANT, but you haven't detached it. When `wrapper` goes out of scope, it destroys the safearray. Then the caller attempts to destroy it the second time, by means of `VariantClear`. This is the immediate cause of your difficulties.

Comment: Detaching does indeed fix the problem. In fact neither attaching nor detaching works too (i.e. just passing in the array to the wrapper constructor) then it does not take control - which was what I was trying to achieve (P.S. thanks for the other fix too).

Comment: When you pass the array to the constructor, `CComSafeArray` makes a copy of the data; then later destroys that copy. See if you are willing to incur this overhead.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification. Here performance is not an issue, so I think I'll stick with making a copy. Maybe time to get hold of ATL Internals...